# login state in top.links when called

Tags: magento

I'm trying to pull the header of our Magento store in a standalone php page.  Everything works as expected except the 'Log In' link does not appear.  The customer.xml file uses the standard 'customer_logged_in' node to 'addLink' but it seems like the login status isn't getting assessed with the method I'm using.  How do I get this Log In | Log Out link to display?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
require_once $mage_path;
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('default')->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

echo $layout->getBlock('header')->toHtml();
```

I'm able to get the correct login state independently using the following:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));       
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    /* logged in */
} else {
    /* not logged in */
}
```

However, I don't want to manage two different styles (one through the default magento XML and another for this custom page).  I would rather have the getBlock call return the whole block with the correct login status.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `customer_logged_in` to your handles, as well as `default`.  For example:

```
...
$handles = array('default');
if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $handles[] 'customer_logged_in';
}
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles);
...
```